# SharePoint passing value of text box on click to update list column

Tags: javascript, custom-list, inputformtextbox

I have a text box on one SP page. Upon click of the submit button, I need the numerical value/input to be sent to a column in a list. I have some coding put together from bits and pieces I've found online, but it doesn't work.

(updated to reflect current code)

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Shipping</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Domestic:</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input id="domesticshippinginput" name="domesticshippinginput" 
type="textbox" /></td>
<td><input name="ADD" id="btnADD" type="button" value="Submit" onclick=
"GetDesc()" /></td>
</tr>

</table>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(updateListItem,'sp.js'); 



function GetDesc()
  {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = 
    clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CurrentTimeFrame');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID" /></OrderBy> 
   <Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value 
 Type="Number">1</Value</Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
    var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(items);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
        if(items.get_count() > 0) { 
            var domesticshippingItem = items.getItemAtIndex(0); 
            domesticshippingItem.set_item('days', 
document.getElementById("domesticshippinginput").value);
            domesticshippingItem.update();

            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, 
this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed);
        }
        else
        {
            alert('List is empty!');
        }
      },
        function (sender, args) {
            alert('Could not retrieve items from list: ' + 
args.get_message());
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

Where CurrentTimeFrame is the name of the list, domesticshipping is the name of the title of the row, and days is the column in the list that I need to update a preset value. Domesticshipping is the very first item in the list. This is all coded in the same Snippet (not sure if that matters), and using SharePoint 2013.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working?  Are you getting an error message displayed by your onQueryFailed?  Or an error occuring before you get to executeQueryAsync?

Comment: Assuming that the ID of the first item will be "1" is not a safe assumption.  The first item created may indeed have an ID of "1", but if that item is deleted and a new item is created, that item would be the first item in the list but would have an ID of "2", and so on.  If you truly want the first item from that list, it would be better to SP.CamlQuery to retrieve items without any filter criteria, sorted by ID, with a RowLimit= "1" to just get whichever item has the smallest ID.  Even better would be to have some unique metadata value you can filter by in your CAMLQuery.

Comment: I apologize, I should've been more clear! When a value is added in the text box, and the submit button is clicked, it does NOT update the value in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, as mentioned in the comments above, you should not assume that
  ID of the first item is 1, you need a more predictable way to get
  your item.
- Second, the `set_item` method should be called from the
  variable that holds the reference to the item you retrieved.  You
  code calls `listItem.set_Item`, but `listItem` is not a defined
  object.
- Finally, the attempt to get the value from the textbox will
  likely not succeed with just a reference to the element's name, you
  need to use document.getElementById to get a reference to the textbox
  and get that element's `value`.

Try the following code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Shipping</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Domestic:</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="domesticshippinginput" name="domesticshippinginput" type="textbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="ADD" id="btnADD" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="saveDomesticShipping()" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function saveDomesticShipping() {
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CurrentTimeFrame');

        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID" /></OrderBy><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Number">1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
        var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(items);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                if (items.get_count() > 0) {
                    var domesticshippingItem = items.getItemAtIndex(0);
                    domesticshippingItem.set_item('days', document.getElementById("domesticshippinginput").value);
                    domesticshippingItem.update();

                    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                        alert('successfully saved new value!');
                        // TODO: better save confirmation
                    },
                        function (sender, args) {
                            alert('Could not update item: ' + args.get_message());
                            // TODO:  better error handling
                        });
                }
                else {
                    alert('List is empty!');
                    // TODO:  better error handling
                }
            },
            function (sender, args) {
                alert('Could not retrieve items from list: ' + args.get_message());
                // TODO:  better error handling
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I did try to replace the code I had used with the code you provided, but it still isn't working. When a value is entered in the text box, and submit is clicked, the page reloads. Then I go to the list to check it, refresh it, but the list has been unaltered. I have training in CPP, so this java is getting the best of me!

Comment: Ah, I missed that mistake too -- change the `type` on your `input` element to be "button" instead of "submit".  "Submit" causes a postback and full page refresh, you just want to trigger your JavaScript, not reload the page.

Comment: I changed it from "submit" to "button". Now the page doesn't refresh, but clicking on Submit doesn't seem to do anything either (the number just stays in the box, nothing on the page changes). Still no update to the list.

Comment: Lol, sorry, I was so focused on your JavaScript, I apparently really dropped the ball on looking at your html.  Add an `onclick = "GetDesc()"` attribute to that same `input` element.

Comment: Even with updating that, it is doing the same thing: click submit,  no change in page, no update to the list. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'll edit my original post to reflect my current code.

Comment: turns out there were multiple html and Javascript syntax errors as well.  I created a list in my local test environment titled `CurrentTimeFrame`, then created a column named `days` and manually added an item to the list.  Then I was able to fully execute and debug this custom code.  I have updated my answer with the tested and validated code.

Comment: First and foremost, I can't tell you just how much I appreciate all of your help! I did update the code. Now I'm getting the error "Could not update item: Column 'days' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user." and then lists the list location. I know it's not the code, but I don't think it's the list either. I do have a list,  with a few rows, and then one column labeled days. I'll mess with it a little and see if I can figure out what is going on now, but if you have any advice, I will gladly listen!

Comment: I added a picture to the original post of the first row in the list, showing the column.

Comment: Possible you originally created this column with a different name, then renamed it to `days`?  All columns have both an "internal" name and a "display" name.  Once a column is created, it's internal name never changes, and is the one you would need to reference via code.  You can change the display name to your hearts content, but the internal name will never change (unless you completely delete and re-create the column with the new name).

Comment: Easiest way to double check the internal name, go to your list settings and open the settings page for that field, then look at the URL, should be `<<yoursiteurl>>/_layouts/15/FldEdit.aspx?List=<<someuniqueidhere>>&Field=<<**whatdoesitsayhere?**>>`

Comment: You sir are AMAZING! I checked the internal column name. It was c3t9. NO IDEA where that came from. I'm only assuming it was assigned it's own identifier when it was created. But the code works and I am so grateful to you!